# Azure functions signalR to create chat app?

Tags: azure-functions, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I'm looking for azure functions with chat application including broadcast, create, update and delete group as well as add, remove user from group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a chat app tutorial which uses Azure function, storage, SignalR service to broadcast messages to chat clients.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-serverless-chat-app-tutorial

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-serverless-chat-app-tutorial/blob/master/lab-instructions.md